# How to display the selected data?

Tags: angular

In general, I have a list of certain entries in the cards. And if click on one of the records on the cards, then the data table belonging to this record will be displayed below this record.

My problem is that after clicking on the record on the selected card to display a table with data. all tables are also displayed on other cards although I didn't even click on them.

html:

```
<div class="col-sm-12" *ngFor="let commitment of filteredCommitments " (click)="onSelectedReportingDate(commitment.commitment_id)" >
    <div class="card card-product">
        <div class="card-content">
            <div class="card-description" [innerHTML]="commitment.commitment_text">
                {{commitment.commitment_text}}
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="selectedCommitment">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align:left; font-size: 10px;">Execution time</th>
                            <th style="text-align:left; font-size: 10px;">Status</th>
                            <th style="text-align:left; font-size: 10px;">Status comment</th>
                            <th style="text-align:right; font-size: 10px;">Documentation</th>
                            <th style="text-align:right; font-size: 10px;">Date of preparation</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody style="cursor: pointer;">
                        <tr *ngFor="let reportingDate of filteredReportingDates">
                            <td style="text-align:left; font-size: 10px;">{{ reportingDate.reportingdate_plan }}</td>
                            <td style="text-align:left; font-size: 10px;">{{ reportingDate.commitment_status_name }}</td>
                            <td style="text-align:left; font-size: 10px;" [innerHTML]="reportingDate.report_text"> {{ reportingDate.report_text }}</td>
                            <td style="text-align:right; font-size: 10px;">{{ reportingDate.file_name }}</td>
                            <td style="text-align:right; font-size: 10px;">{{ reportingDate.reportingdate_fakt }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ts:

```
commitments: Array<SprLiability>;

selectedCommitment = null;
reportingDates: Array<ReportingDate>
filteredReportingDates = [];

onSelectedReportingDate(commitmentId) {
  this.selectedCommitment = this.commitments.find(
    el => {
      return el.commitment_id === commitmentId
    }
  );

  let filteredReportingDates;
  if (this.servReportingDate) {
    this.servReportingDate.getReportingDates().subscribe(
      reportingDate => {
        this.reportingDates = reportingDate;
        this.filteredReportingDates = this.reportingDates.filter(
          (reportingDate) => reportingDate.l_liabilitys_id == this.selectedCommitment.commitment_id
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update Code:
From
`<div *ngIf="selectedCommitment">`
To

```
<div *ngIf="selectedCommitment.commitment_id == commitment.commitment_id ">
```

Table will only show when selected commitment_id will only match with commitment_id in filteredCommitments array.

Hope this may helps you!